# Center yticklabels in horizontal barplot - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any way to center the yticklabels in the middle of a horizontal barplot that has both negative and positive values?  I want the names of various y-values (stored in a list called 'names') to appear in the middle of a barplot (centered at x=0).  Is this possible?

Demo code:

```
names = [1, 2, 3]
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3,1, figsize=(12, 24)) 
ind = np.arange(len(names))  # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars
axs[0].barh(ind, [3, 4, 5], width, color='red', label='demo')
axs[0].set(yticks=ind + width, yticklabels=names)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. You just need to use `align=center` and then rename the tick-labels as you are doing **without** shifting the ticks by `0.5`. I replaced `coef_names` by `names` because the former was not defined in your provided code.

```
names = [1, 2, 3]
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3,1, figsize=(12, 24)) 
ind = np.arange(len(names))  # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars
axs[0].barh(ind, [3, 4, 5], width, color='red', align='center',label='demo')
axs[0].set(yticks=ind , yticklabels=names)
```

[image]